# Limit RDP use with certificate

Tags: networking, security, remote-desktop, certificate

I need help with RDP in home environment.

**I need to access my home computer from my class with RDP and I only want to allow access to remote machines that have a certificate issued by me (yes, I issued a certificate my self, copied on a stick and imported it in the classroom pc).**

I also configured RDP from GPO to use that specific certificate, but when I tried to access it from a different machine (tested from mobile too), it offered a default generated cert, thus allowing the connection.

How can I force it to use the issued certificate and stop it from allowing connection if that certificate is not present on the connecting device?

I don't have a server or AD or anything of sorts (for now), it's just a simple desktop with Windows 10 Pro... I'm studying Network and Systems Administration and we work a lot in VMs and I'm tired of having to clone machines back and forth to finish my practices, I want to access the VM at home directly, and since I can only get access and custom ports open by having a public IP (and out of CG-NAT infrastructure), I'm completely open to RDP attacks.

I do have separate accounts for the users that I use with RDP but they have access the other drives/partitions and parts of the files of the admin account (since I might need to get something from my Desktop, Documents) and I don't want to mess with user permissions for now. I still think the most secure option in this case will be blocking access if no certificate is present.

Comment: I don't think that this particular limitation exists, but there are other methods to secure RDP, if you're interested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RDP with client authentication via a certificate or a key file](https://superuser.com/questions/1678656/rdp-with-client-authentication-via-a-certificate-or-a-key-file)

Comment: Here's another way to do what you're looking for using IPSEC: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/securing-rdp-with-ipsec/ba-p/259108. In the Authentication Method section, you would choose Advanced > Customize > Add... > Computer certificate from this certification authority (CA), and browse to the CA cert that signed the cert you're using to authenticate.

Comment: Both solutions are out of scope, one is offering VPN which I can't use and the other GPO that  I can not implement on the remote machine since it's already in the school domain and I can't touch anything, let alone the firewall or kerberos